# replace negative numbers in array to zero

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

How to replace a negative number in an array with the value of 0 in JavaScript e.g.

```
[1,5,10,-2] will become [1,5,10,0]
```

I tried

```
function noNeg(arr) {
  let num 
  return num = arr < 0 ? 0 : arr
}
```

but it only returns the negative into positive not zero.

Comment: Hint: `Math.max(num, 0)`. Just apply that to every number in the array. `Array.map` would come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

Simply map over the array and apply a ternary to return 0 if less than 0 ... or the value if greater than 0.

```js
const arr = [1,5,10,-2];

const newArr = arr.map(num => num < 0  ? 0 : num);

console.log(newArr); // gives [1,5,10,0]
```